# Nash equilibria and bifurcation point

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, bifurcation

I have a non-cooperative game involving a number of players. I computed the Nash equilibria which depend on a parameter $\alpha$. For $\alpha<\alpha_0$ there exist two Nash equilibria, e.g. $P$ and $Q$, for $\alpha=\alpha_0$ we have that $P\equiv Q$ while for $\alpha>\alpha_0$ we have only one of them, $P$.

Then, is $\alpha_0$ a bifurcation point? I'm asking because I know that the notion of bifurcation point is usually associated to ODE (or to a system of ODEs) that depends on a parameter, while in my case I don't have ODE (but players with utility functions).

Comment: There is a notion of a [_catastrophe_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_theory#The_smooth_theory_and_catastrophes) when a change in critical points of smooth function or mapping depending on parameters is being discussed. However, I presume, in game theory there is very rarely a smooth objective function, it is more likely to be piecewise-smooth at best?